# How to mock _auto_now?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an ndb.model class with a 'created_on' field that has auto_now_add set to true.

```
created_on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, indexed=True)
```

I'm testing a method 'create()' that creates objects of this class. Here's what I'm essentially doing in the test:

- Create an object using the 'create()' method being tested.
- Fetch the object.
- Compare with a stub(created without using the 'create()' method).

The problem is that I'm not able to set the 'created_on' to match that of the stub.

How do I mock something like this ? (Is there an api being used in the backend that I can mock ?)

Comment: Note that the value is being set completely in Python code; the datastore api has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I've used [`freezegun`](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) to mock this sort of thing.  It'd look something like:

```
@freezegun.freeze_time('2015-9-21')
def test():
    assert ModelClass.create(...) == ModelClass(...)
```

If you don't like that, you can call `to_dict` on the two models and pop out the `'created_on'` attribute.